# Reader, when did non-fiction writers start breaking the fourth wall?

Tags: idioms, history, literary-techniques

**[Breaking the fourth wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall)** is usually considered a theatrical concept, but Wikipedia notes that it can also occur in literature (ie. fiction).

> Use of the fourth wall in literature can be traced back as far as *The Canterbury Tales* and *Don Quixote* … However, it was popularized in the early 20th century during the post-modern literary movement. Artists like Virginia Woolf in *To the Lighthouse* and Kurt Vonnegut in *Breakfast of Champions* used the genre to question the accepted knowledge and sources of the culture.

The phrase **dear reader** is an idiomatic way to do this in modern English. An example is provided in response to this Writing.SE question about fiction:

- [In ancient writings, was it usual to address the reader?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/47753/in-ancient-writings-was-it-usual-to-address-the-reader) – *Roy, the hero of this tale, was indeed an idiot. But you know that by now, don't you dear reader?*

“Dear reader” is also used in non-fiction writing. For example, some users of this Stack Exchange use “dear reader” to add a bit of sarcasm or “snark” to their posts:

- [Can you use "(sic)" in other contexts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16649/can-you-use-sic-in-other-contexts) – *That would be an ironic extension of the regular usage of sic. I’d interpret it as “yes, **dear reader**, surprising as it may be, this is what he did.”*
- [“just because… doesn't mean…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/just-because-doesnt-mean/1534) – *I’ve just discovered the wonderful Corpus of Historical American English, and you, **dear reader**, get see the first fruits of my research there.*
- [Have unnecessary quotation marks evolved?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161676/have-unnecessary-quotation-marks-evolved) – *For some time, I've had an odd fascination with commercial supply branding … Judge me not, **dear reader**.*

Another way to do this is to begin a sentence with the salutation **Reader**. This is harder to search for, but I think it’s quite common in online writing about feminism and science fiction. A pre-internet example can be found in Carol Cohn, [Sex and Death in the Rational World of Defense Intellectuals](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3174209) (1987):

> Yet what is striking about the men themselves is not, as the content of
> their conversations might suggest, their cold-bloodedness. Rather, it is
> that they are a group of men unusually endowed with charm, humor,
> intelligence, concern, and decency. **Reader,** I liked them. At least, I liked many of them. The attempt to understand how such men could contribute
> to an endeavor that I see as so fundamentally destructive became a continuing obsession for me, a lens through which I came to examine all of my experiences in their world.

Is there a more precise name for this technique than “breaking the fourth wall”? Does the non-fiction technique have a distinct history to its use in fiction? Am I right to think it’s particularly common in writing about feminism and science fiction?

Comment: You're finding editor's comments of the *Nota Bene* type written as Dear Reader. Charming if not overused. Seems like a style thing, not a subject matter thing.

Comment: Why did you ask this question here, on a site for a language that's maybe about 1500 years old? One of the most well-known English works addresses the audience directly: ["thou shalt not kill"](https://biblehub.com/exodus/20-13.htm), translating from a language much older than itself.

Comment: Addressing the audience is not necessarily *breaking the fourth wall*.  In most forms of communication, there is no fourth wall to break.  An imaginary fourth wall lets us pretend to observe actors without them knowing they're being observed, or that they're characters in a story.  In fiction, a narrator cannot break the fourth wall. The narrator always addresses the audience.  Only a character who should not know they are a character in a story can *break the fourth wall* (by addressing the audience, or an omniscient narrator).  Non-fiction lacks characters who don't know they're in a story.

Comment: Belongs on Writers SE ........

Comment: Regarding your first question, people often call this technique "direct address". (That term can also refer to other situations, though, so perhaps it's not very precise.) I do agree with others, though, that this isn't really an ELU topic.

Comment: The use of "Reader..." in feminist writings must be a conscious reference to the famous opening of the last chapter of _Jane Eyre_ - "Reader, I married him".

Comment: Belongs on Literature SE if it's asking when a device was first used in literature (which includes non-fiction). But there seem to be multiple questions.

Comment: Thanks, @KateBunting – if you repost your comment as an answer, I’ll accept it. I didn’t post this on Writing.SE because my question is about etymology (I’m not writing fiction or looking for style advice), and I didn’t post it on Literature.SE because as others have pointed out, my question is not strictly about “breaking the fourth wall” in fiction.

Comment: @sjy If you're asking about etymology (the historical development of a term), then that's not clear from your post's title or from any of the three questions you ask at the end of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer all the OP's questions, but, as requested...

Starting a comment with "Reader..." in feminist writings must be a conscious reference to the famous opening of the final section of Charlotte Brontë's *Jane Eyre* (1847) -

> Reader, I married him.